# How do I get around "Filename too long" error when running `chef install` on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, chef-infra, policyfiles

I'm transitioning from berkshelf to the Policyfile workflow, and everything was running fine until I attempted to resolve all the dependencies. Two of my dependencies are from git, so when I run `chef install` in the cookbook directory, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to generate Policyfile.lock
Reason: (CookbookOmnifetch::GitCommandError) Git error: command `git reset --hard 7e5e4bccf57718cacc246f1b4d501ff7de8ac13d` failed. If this error persists, 
try removing the cache directory at 'C:/Users/pcummuskey/AppData/Local/chefdk/cache/.cache/git/780b7dbee933c3a9efbfd3898d54cdf72784fa7e'.Output from the command:

error: unable to create file test/kitchen/.kitchen/tmp/librarian/cache/source/chef/site/877777683730772c36b1e6a3fc3aa2c3/windows/version-uri/a3432e93fb3c21cb7111fde71e435661/package/files/default/handlers/windows_reboot_handler.rb: Filename too long
Checking out files: 100% (389/389), done.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision '7e5e4bccf57718cacc246f1b4d501ff7de8ac13d'.
```

Predictably, removing the cache folder had zero effect on the problem. I'm in the middle of checking whether I can get it working in the ubuntu subsystem and/or docker atm, but it'd be nice to be able to run it natively on Windows.

Comment: Can you subst a drive letter for the common prefix on those paths in order to shorten the overall path?  (I know nothing about chef, but I've used the subst trick several times in other forms of automation.)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy What part of the path would I subst? I'd have to configure how librarian interacts with the filesystem to mess with anything but the project dir, and that's at `C:\code\chef\proj_nginx`

Comment: Have you tried enabling NTFS long paths? I'm not sure if that will work for Ruby but it is worth a shot.

Comment: @coderanger Just did that and absolutely no change, sadly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're just SOL.

Comment: @coderanger (ﾉಥ益ಥ）ﾉ ┻━┻

Comment: Maybe try using wsl?

Comment: @Tzrik:  The max path length on Windows is typical 260 characters, and the relative path shown in the error message is about 200, so I assume that path is relative to a base path on the order of 60 or more characters.  Use subst to replace the base path with a drive letter.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Any idea how I can set the chef cache path? I've tried using the librarian environment vars to no effect, and setting `file_cache_path` in `client.rb` as well. Getting the keywords right on google searches for this is proving to be more difficult than anticipated.

@coderanger Windows Single Language?

Comment: @Tzrik:  As I wrote in my first comment.  I know nothing about chef.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Ah yes, evidently I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work around the issue by making a local cookbooks folder and checking out the dependencies to there and referencing them by path. It's not pretty, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this problem using *"git bash"* (MINGW64) packaged in [Git for windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) installer.

As an example:

```
$ pwd
/c/Users/foobar/AppData/Local/chefdk/cache/.cache/git/13036489648c6f8811262c6a50ff6b03da2395b7/4416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f64416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f64416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f64416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f6/4416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f64416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f64416ca3886d025b3ead519f1ee53af03ecb630f61
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get exactly the same error. The git command being invoked appears to be running in a CMD context, so no matter which shell I run `chef install` on, it'll give me the same problem.